# JavaScript - getting text from <strong> or div by class

Tags: javascript

I wonder how to get data from this code. I want to download these numbers, but I don't know how.
I have already tried such methods but they did not work.

```
document.querySelector('.myclass');
document.querySelector('.myclass strong');
document.querySelectorAll('.myclass strong');
```

And this is the element from which I want to get the numbers. There are two ways on the site but I don't know which will be better so I send 2 items with numbers

```
<div class="myclass" role="button" tabindex="0">Next number: <strong>97554</strong></div>
```

or

```
<div class="anyclass">97532</div>
```

Comment: *"...but they did not work."* Did not work **how**? What did the actual code you used look like? The second one, `document.querySelector('.myclass strong');`, is correct provided you do something with the element once you have it (and provided you want the first matching element).

Comment: shows null or NodeList []

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
document.querySelector('.myClass').innerHTML;    
document.querySelector('.myClass').innerText;
```

Use the data-* attribute to embed custom data. eg:

```
 <div class='myClass' data-price="123"> Your ticket costs <i> 123 </i> </div>
```

Then you can use

```
 document.querySelector('.myClass').getAttribute('data-price');
```

Comment: unfortunately there is no access to change it because it is on the page and I can't edit it. I needed a way to download this item without change

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.innerText` to get the numbers in the strong tag

```
document.querySelector('.myClass strong').innerText;
```